# Creating a generic based on class Type

Tags: c#, generics

If I had generic class:

```
public class GenericTest<T> : IGenericTest {...}
```

and I had an instance of Type, which I got through reflection, how could I instantiate GenericType with that Type?  For example:

```
public IGenericTest CreateGenericTestFromType(Type tClass)
{
   return (IGenericTest)(new GenericTest<tClass>());
}
```

Of course, the above method won't compile, but it illustrates what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [Type.MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx):

```
public IGenericTest CreateGenericTestFromType(Type tClass)
{
   Type type = typeof(GenericTest<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { tClass });
   return (IGenericTest) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```